# How is referential integrity maintained in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

RedShift does not support any constraint. They do not support enforcing contrainsts such as referential constriants. They only have informational constraints.

How would referential integrity be maintained in RedShift? Would we have to manually place a bunch of triggers?

Answer (score 4):

You have to accept the burden of checking constraints in your ETL and weigh how important a given constraint is.

In a 'classic' data warehouse scenario the data mostly comes from traditional row based DBs where the data integrity is enforced. In this case Redshift is being used to provide speed and/or scale and constraint checking is not the priority.

In a 'modern' data lake scenario data mostly comes from non-relational sources and often has "at least once" delivery characteristics, e.g., a certain amount of duplication is expected.

In my Redshift hourly load ETL I do the following (adding 100 million rows or more per day):

- Merge tables: (a few million to a few hundred million rows)

  - Perform merge
  - Analyze table (takes 2-10 sec per table) `ANALYZE merge_table;`
  - Verify PK: `SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT pk_col) FROM merge_table;`

    - Surprisingly fast at 2-10 sec per table.
- Append only tables: (billions of rows)

  - Perform append
  - Do not analyze (too slow, not necessary)
  - Verify PK only on new data range: `SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT pk_col) FROM merge_table WHERE timestamp_col >= {new_data_start_timestamp};`

    - Note that you want your `timestamp_col` to be defined as the `SORTKEY`.
    - Should only take a few seconds as long as the the sort key is used.

Comment: Wow - nice illustration. It makes sense that if we're digesting a ton of data, that it would be unscalable to check constraints

Answer (score 0):

Triggers would be an option but they aren't supported in Redshift either. Assuming you are using Redshift for a datawarehouse function, the burden would be on your ETL processes to ensure that data maintains referential integrity.

Comment: How do people do this in the real-world? What if there are issues with referential integrity? Do they just do periodic clean ups? (I believe these are called vacuums)

Comment: In the real world? I don't know I'm still assessing the product. vacuums are nothing to do with foreign keys. You can have an invalid foreign key and a vacuum won't care. vacuum is more is to do with performance, not data integrity. So I assume you are intending using Redshift for a data warehouse and the only way data gets in is through an ETL process?